# Github pages issue with username

Tags: github, github-pages

I have followed [this](https://pages.github.com/) guide to setup my GitHub Pages. My username is FReina, and therefore I thought that my website would be at `FReina.github.io`. However, I consistently get a 404.
Anybody know if this is due to the uppercase in my username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is simply caused by the fact that there is latency between your username.github.io repository on Github and the actual hosted website. Usually this is only a few minutes, but I have known it to be much longer than that when the site is busy.

From my PC, it looks like your site is now up, and displaying a Hello World page. If you still cannot see it, it may be that the 404 page is cached by your browser - try emptying your browser cache (on Chromium-based browsers including Google Chrome and newer versions of MS Edge, this is done by opening the Inspect Element tool, clicking-and-holding the reload button and selecting "Empty cache and hard-refresh")

Comment: Thank you very much!